# Laravel eloquent order by group by with eager loading

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a query that runs group by and order by with eager loading and it seems group by works fine but order by doesn't work.

```
Message::whereIn('conversation_id',$msgs)
        ->where('deleted', '!=', $userId)
        ->with(array('last_sender' =>function($query) use ($userId){
                $query->where('id','!=', $userId);
                $query->select('id', 'userName', 'profilePic','firstName', 'lastName');
          }))

         ->with(array('last_reciever' =>function($query) use ($userId){
                $query->where('id','!=', $userId);
                $query->select('id', 'userName', 'profilePic','firstName', 'lastName');
          }))
         ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
         ->orderBy('conversation_id', 'desc') 
         ->groupBy('id')
         ->groupBy('conversation_id')
         ->get();
```

It returns data like this

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": 133,
        "conversation_id": 13,
        "last_sender": null,
        "last_reciever": {
            "id": 55,
            "userName": "buyer",
            "profilePic": "pRBDBFJW55baSnF560Ajid8jTgPo5kmg4i5LMhPG.jpeg",
            "firstName": "Matti",
            "lastName": "Rames"
        },
        "msg": "second message 2 to user second",
        "attachment": null,
        "deleted": 0,
        "seen": 0,
        "created_at": "2017-10-17 15:43:14",
        "updated_at": "2017-10-17 15:43:14"
    },
    {
        "id": 132,
        "conversation_id": 11,
        "last_sender": null,
        "last_reciever": {
            "id": 54,
            "userName": "Sadek",
            "profilePic": "Nir7zgorNT2dmwcXJdhNK3ZmPAltmkEnj0SXDCDC.png",
            "firstName": "Sadek",
            "lastName": "Hossain"
        },
        "msg": "second message to first user",
        "attachment": null,
        "deleted": 0,
        "seen": 0,
        "created_at": "2017-10-17 15:38:16",
        "updated_at": "2017-10-17 15:38:16"
    },
    {
        "id": 131,
        "conversation_id": 13,
        "last_sender": null,
        "last_reciever": {
            "id": 55,
            "userName": "buyer",
            "profilePic": "pRBDBFJW55baSnF560Ajid8jTgPo5kmg4i5LMhPG.jpeg",
            "firstName": "Matti",
            "lastName": "Rames"
        },
        "msg": "second message to second user",
        "attachment": null,
        "deleted": 0,
        "seen": 0,
        "created_at": "2017-10-17 15:37:49",
        "updated_at": "2017-10-17 15:37:49"
    },
    {
        "id": 130,
        "conversation_id": 11,
        "last_sender": null,
        "last_reciever": {
            "id": 54,
            "userName": "Sadek",
            "profilePic": "Nir7zgorNT2dmwcXJdhNK3ZmPAltmkEnj0SXDCDC.png",
            "firstName": "Sadek",
            "lastName": "Hossain"
        },
        "msg": "Hi how are you",
        "attachment": null,
        "deleted": 0,
        "seen": 0,
        "created_at": "2017-10-17 15:36:49",
        "updated_at": "2017-10-17 15:36:49"
    }
]
```

}

But I only want to return the first two latest results. Only id `133` and `132` 
I know I added `->groupBy('id')` which is useless here and returning the all records. I added it just to show what my data are. So if I remove `->groupBy('id')` then it only returns id `131` and `130`

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I solve it adding one extra line :) 
I am posting for other's helps.

```
->orderBy('created_at', 'desc') 
->get()
->unique('conversation_id');
```